# How can I go to the previous edited location on gedit?

Tags: gedit

I am trying to go to the previous edited location on gedit. I have installed the following plugin by moving files to the ***~/.local/share/gedit/plugins*** but the plugin has the following sign on the menu:

[image]

Is there any other way to go to the previous edited location on gedit?

```
Gedit Version : 3.28.1
Ubuntu Version :  18.04.2 LTS
```

Thanks, WinEunuuchs2Unix. The bookmark feature is really helpful. But I need to switch with hotkeys to not lose time. "Menu>Toggle Bookmark" and "Menu>Return Previous bookmark" is time consuming on productivity perspective when you need to return the previous location hundreds of times a day.

Source:https://www.linuxnov.com/10-advanced-plugins-features-to-gedit-text-editor/

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu and gedit and the source (and version) of the plugin.

Comment: You mean 18.04—riight ?

Comment: Also what plugins you try to install ? Please add it to your post

Comment: The bookmarks feature might be helpful to you: https://www.linuxnov.com/10-advanced-plugins-features-to-gedit-text-editor/

Answer (score 0):

If the plugin you're referring to is [gedit-back-forward](https://github.com/oliver/gedit-back-forward), it had its last commit on July 25 2009. In other words, it probably is no longer maintained or compatible with your current version of gedit.